# D - Exception not handled by scope statement

Tags: d

Why does this code result in an exception during runtime, when I would expect it to be handled by the [`scope`](http://ddili.org/ders/d.en/scope.html) statement?

```
void scopeTest(ref int i) {
  i = 10 / i;
  scope(failure) i = 0;
}
...
int j = 0;
j.scopeTest;
```

The same runtime error happens with `scope(exit)` being used instead.

When compiling with -run flag with ldc, I get `Error: message: Floating point exception (core dumped)
Error: program received signal 2 (Interrupt)`. With dmd, I get `Error: program killed by signal 8`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a processor exception. The `scope(failure)` only occurs to D language exceptions (which only includes system and processor things on 32-bit Windows!).

Comment: sorry, having trouble wrapping my mind around this. can you provide an example of a 'D language exception' that would trigger the scope statement (not necessarily in the code above)?

Comment: `throw new Exception("msg");`

Answer (score 2):

scope(failure) is only executed when a Dlang exception is throwed. But in this particular case, this is a processor error, catched by your operating systems detecing a division by zero and proceeding to kill your process (because it assumes your process is in an invalid state). The right way is to catch the error yourself is NEVER EXECUTE invalid operations (A simple IF clause can help to solve this particular division by zero problem, but applies to segment faults too)

(It doesn't sound very practical but is a design trade-off. Better make YOUR program check for invalid operations when needed and BEFOREHAND than complicate compilers, portability, over-coupling compilers/libraries with non-portable OS/CPU specific stuff and (most important) slow-down overall performance because error handling is happening AFTERWARDS)

Answer (score 0):

My reading of the explanation in Programming in D is that the `scope(failure)` does not catch or prevent the exception, it just makes sure that the code runs in the event of an exception. A bit like a `catch{}` block that does something in the case of an exception, and then re-throws the same exception, but cleaner.

The book (and the [language spec](https://dlang.org/spec/statement.html#scope-guard-statement)) speak of **exiting the scope due to an exception**. If `scope` caught or prevented the exception then it would not cause the execution to leave that scope.

The example at the bottom of PinD `scope` also shows the `object.Exception`, even though the code contained multiple `scope(failure)` statements.

(I am a pretty experienced but not a very experienced D programmer.)